# Unknown devices on router WiFi without password knowledge

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, home-networking, wifi-configuration

I am facing a new (to me) situation. My ISP provided me with a Zyxel DX5401-B0 modem/router. Recently, I noticed in the list of connected devices a few ones listed as "unknown", with MAC addresses that I don't recognize. I changed passwords on both main and guest networks, but the devices don't disapper. At least with one of them, I could actually ping it.

Is it possible for a device to connect to a router without knowing the password?

Comment: Get Advanced IP Scanner (Famatech) and scan you local network.

Comment: “Is it possible for a device to connect to a router without knowing the password?” - No, it is NOT possible.

Comment: talk to your ISP

Comment: Can it be some connected devices that you have at home, such as phones, TV, home appliances etc? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: I've seen it twice. First time, they were things like Android TV on the tv I connected, so it was actually correct. Second was that my wifi was actually hacked, because apparently the password was too weak

Comment: Have you enabled weak authentication methods like WEP or WPA? Only use WPA2 or WPA3, if possible only WPA3.

Comment: Try Nirsoft's free Wireless Network Watcher, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_network_watcher.html, to get more info. BTW, one device, such as your PC, may show multiple connections.

Comment: It's probably a smartphone or other device doing MAC address privacy (where it autogenerates random MAC addresses to be less trackable), or some IoT device you're not thinking of right now. Can you edit your question to include the first half of each unrecognized MAC address? The 2's place bit of the first octet lets us know if the MAC address was autogenerated. The first three octets together (the first half of the address) lets us know the vendor of the device, or at least the vendor of the chipset used, which can be a good clue. Also some connected devices lists will show wired devices too.